# Need help with Angular and isolate scopes and directives w/o templates

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying the following scenario without success (with angular 1.4.7) and was hoping for some pointers on how to proceed. I have the following HTML (simplified) as an Angular view (and use $route, etc.)

The pagedListController contains a function 'selectStuff($event)'.

```
<div ng-controller="domainController as pageCtrl">
    <div paged-list api="pageCtrl.api">
        <button ng-click="pgList.selectStuff($event)"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and a directive (again, simplified) of the following

```
app.directive('pagedList', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: {},
       bindToController: {
          api: '='
       },
       controller: 'pagedListController',
       controllerAs: 'pgList',
       compile: function(tElem, tAttrs, transcludeFn) {
           function linkFn(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
               transcludeFn(scope, function(clone, scope) {
                   element.append(clone);
               }
           }

           return linkFn;
       }
   };
```

})

The problem: while 'api' binds correctly, references to pgList in the content of the paged-list directive never actually call selectStuff(). I cannot for the life of me understand why not. I've looked through the angular docs and a couple dozen blogs and other posts and just don't see what's wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks - I had thought I was in the right area, but I see now I was mistaken. Thanks for moving it where I was trying to put it originally.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

The original presentation above actually had an error that made all the difference, I wrote it as

```
function linkFn(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) {
    transcludeFn(scope, function(clone, scope) {
        element.append(clone);
    }
}
```

which was incorrect in my real code.

My real code called transcludeFn() with no 'scope' initial parameter, just the callback function (the 'scope' param is optional in the transcludeFn).

What I didn't understand, but which was explained tremendously well by a post in the Angular Tips blog (http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/03/transclusion-and-scopes/), is that the default scope of the transcluded content (i.e., the button) in paged-list is the scope of paged-list's PARENT, not paged-list.

The way to get the button's scope to be the paged-list scope is to set that optional first 'scope' parameter in the transcludeFn. The transcluded content's scope then uses that scope as its own. Unspecified, that parameter is by default set to paged-list-scope.$parent. Forcing it to the paged-list scope instead fixes everything, since that's where pgList is defined.

Thanks to blog-post author Jesus Rodriguez for the very clear explanation of how this all really works.